# Add a price from the stock exchange to mobile app in flutter

Tags: flutter

i want to add a gold price from the stock exchange to variable in flutter to mobile app, can someone give me some tips? Thanks a lot, wish u a good day :)

```
.
```

Comment: Hi @czeslov, welcome to Stack Overflow. The question you've asked is not in line with Stack Overflow guidelines and hence got downvoted. I would recommend you to add more details such as: The source of Gold data, and how are you planning to fetch them, any code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an API to do that. Here is an example of a place you could get it from:

https://www.metals-api.com/

The API would give you a JSON format with which you'll have to iterate over the JSON data and get the prices of whatever commodities(eg: gold, silver, etc) you want. If you are new to API and JSON I would first research on that.

Comment: Thanks and i need to do research, i am new in this env. so i dont know how to use json.